# How to automate data importing, add time stamp, and standardize the number of rows in data files in R

Tags: r

I have a folder that contains 1900 dataset (.dat), it's 1-day food-consumption data from 2012-2017. 
They are named according to date like this:

```
 FC-20120204.dat 
 FC-20120205.dat 
 FC-20120206.dat
```

In each dataset contains 1500 column (1500 variables), 1440 rows (1-minute data).

My problems are these:

1. A lot of the dataset is not complete i.e. only 899 rows, 1101 rows
2. There is not date/time stamp, so it can be confusing
3. I need only data from the time stamp and column 25th.
4. These data is supposed to be continuous, so I have to eventually rbind them together.

But first I figure I need to do:

1. find a way to standardized all datasets to contain exactly 1440 rows.

So far I've tried these from my previous question in stackoverflow:

```
files<-list.files(pattern="FC")
result <- sapply(files, function(file) {
temp <- read.csv(file) # adjustments may be needed for headers, etc.
temp[,25]
})
```

it worked well until suddenly the R Studio crashed. I guess it's because I have 1900 dataset (the whole dataset is about 9 GB. My computer RAM is only 8 GB). So list.files function is not applicable, and i guess sapply and lapply is not applicable as well.

I guess have to automate it one by one i.e. import one file at a time, add in the time stamp, standardize every file to contain 1440 rows, select the desired column, save it as a new .dat file, repeat with another file.

After that, I can import all the 1900 new files (much smaller this time with only two columns) and rbind them together.

Or is there an easier way to go about this?

Update: Three of the dataset can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17Rq1Vx21VqZhwYKWl9HLWZzxoZh2mxIh?usp=sharing. The most important data is column C.

or dropbox here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q6c9w8kryn2by5z/AAD3rPnBgP5CyRy7E5eautJGa?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried to loop over the files instead of using sapply?. I'm assuming (might be incorrect) that vectorizing in this case might be more resourceful than looping. In addition, you can use data.table::fread() which will be faster and efficient and you'll be able to select the column you want

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: FIrst, don't use `for`, stick with `lstofframes <- sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` initially. Do the data cleaning, then `do.call(rbind, lstofframes)`. Second, standardizin to 1440 rows (assuming 1/minute) can be done by merging/joining each table with a single-column table you generate for each day, easy enough in theory. Third, since it's large-ish data, it might be beneficial to load the file, standardize the date/time stamp stuff, fill in missing rows, then save to a temp-file; concat all temp files, then load at once (assuming your mem problem is processing). Otherwise: think SQL.

Comment: Let me change that ... `for` would be good for this due to the resource issues, especially if (as I ended my previous comment) you process and then re-read later.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, tried do.call(rbind, list) but wouldnt load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with large-ish data^1 can be dealt with in a few ways.

1. I would be remiss if I did not suggest a ("proper") SQL database.
2. Load/process only a small chunk at a time, aggregating only at the end. That is, do *some* of what I mention below, trying to reduce your "currently used data" to one day or several days at a time.
3. If you can load all data at once but just can't load the incremental pieces and work on them without exceeding memory, then try the technique below.

---

## Sample Data

(This creates files in your working directory.)

```
x1 <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
X1,X2,X3
10,07:00,30
11,07:01,31
12,07:02,32
13,07:03,33
15,07:05,35
16,07:06,36
18,07:08,38
19,07:09,39')
write.csv(x1, file="20120204.dat", row.names=FALSE)
x2 <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
X1,X2,X3
20,07:00,40
22,07:02,42
23,07:03,43
24,07:04,44
25,07:05,45
26,07:06,46')
write.csv(x1, file="20120205.dat", row.names=FALSE)
```

If you can do it with two files, you can do it with two thousand. In this case, the second column is "time", inferring from your question that the only way to infer date/time is from the filename and this field. (Note that in the process below, `merge` will put the joining key as the first column, so the order *will* change. You can of course strong-arm this.)

---

## The Work

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern=".*\\.dat", full.names=TRUE)
first <- TRUE
times <- c("00:00", "23:59")
for (fn in fnames) {
  thisdate <- gsub(".*(20[0-9]{6}).dat", "\\1", fn)
  twotimes <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, c("00:00", "23:59")), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
  allminutes <- data.frame(X2 = seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min"))
  dat <- read.csv(fn, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
  dat <- merge(dat, allminutes, by="X2", all=TRUE)
  write.table(dat, "alldata.csv", append=!first,
              col.names=first, row.names=FALSE, sep=",", na="")
  first <- FALSE
  rm(dat)
  gc() # optional, if you really want/need to control memory management *now*
}
```

Step-through:

1. `times`, `twotimes`, and `allminutes` are all used to fill-out the data.frame so that you always have at least 1,440 rows. I say "at least" because this makes sure you have one occurrence at "00" seconds of every minute. If you have something else, then you'll need to temporarily create a "0-second" time column in each frame or some other technique to enable the merge. If you look at `allminutes`, you'll see that it is 1440 rows, 1 column, that is all, but it must be created for each day.
2. `thisdate`: I'm extracting the date component from the filename; the pattern might differ for you, but there should be sufficient resources for forming this based on your filenames.
3. `as.POSIXct(...)`: combining `thisdate` and the time field (`X2`), create a true date/time object (to replace the time strings).
4. `merge()` will effectively add a row for missing times, with `NA` values for all other columns.
5. `write.table(..., append=!first, col.names=first, ...)` appends the data to a CSV, only including the header row on the first pass through the loop.
6. `rm(dat)` and `gc()` forces a garbage-collect, which typically will remove `dat` from memory. This is typically inefficient, not necessary, and at times not desired, but in your case it is a forced safeguard. It is possible that it will work (automagically garbage-collecting unused data) without this, feel free to test and report back.

### Assumptions

1. You can deal with all of the data in memory at one time (perhaps using `data.table`), just not with loading and modifying all of it multiple times.
2. By the way: if you will have 9GB of data without filling in the missing rows, then you will only increase the file size, and therefore you will likely never be able to load this one file into your 8GB computer instance of R. This answer is not useless: you now have a better-formatting single-file for the data, which can then be imported into a database or similar.

### Database?

As I mentioned earlier, that much data for your local use really begs either increasing your RAM (a lot) or, perhaps more elegantly, the use of a database. It is feasible to use SQLite (via `RSQLite`) for a local-only, no-server database, as they can handle data that large. Depending on your prowess, however, it's not hard to spin up a single docker container with `postgres`, `mariadb`, or even [`mssql-server-linux`](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/).

---

^1: *"large data"* might be classified based on how much you can do on your computer; if you cannot load it given your RAM and the language/tool, then it is "large" to you.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, while it worked great with dummy data, I have not try it on my actual dataset.
I will report back here after I've tried it

Comment: dear @r2evans, I've tried the method using dummy data and it worked great. However, when I use it on my dataset, there is a problem at the 

` dat <- merge(dat, allminutes, by="X2", all=TRUE)`

after running this line, the dataset will be merged into three columns, the timestamp column will come first (1: 1440 rows), then followed by data in column2 and 3 (row 1441 : 2880). 

Also,  
I encountered this error as well: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  first five rows are empty: giving up

Comment: *"first five rows are empty"* ... completely different problem, perhaps based on an incorrect assumption on the data files. *"timestamp column will come first"*, this is a problem? Can't you just rearrange them (assuming that you really need them to be in that specific order) with `dat <- `dat[c(2,3,1)]` or whatever order you feel relevant?

Comment: hi @r2evans, I trimmed down my data down to only two sets and tried again, and found that the problem occurs at merge.

So i tried using dat3<-cbind(dat, allminutes) to replace the merge command and it achieved what i needed. But that's only for two files.... I will try again using the list of files in fnames.

Also I will try again using the complete dataset and let you know about the "first five rows are empty" error

Comment: UPDATE: yes I've tried again and the problem comes from "merge" command. When I merge the "dat" and "allminutes" by X2, it's supposed to give me 1440 rows with 3 columns. But now it's giving me 2880 rows with 3 columns, with the X2 column becoming empty from row 1441 onward.  I'm currently checking all resources on "merge" and will report back here.

Comment: The problem merge doesn't work well is because of one error in dat$X2. According to your command, the dat$X2<-as.POSIXct.....line is supposed to paste the date in the dat dataframe as X2, which it failed to do (only appears as NA in dat$X2). That's why the merge command failed. I'm now tryng to edit the command to see if i can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: If the `as.POSIXct` command is producing `NA`, then there is something you are not telling us. I suggest you look at `thisdate` to see how/why it is different, it sounds like you'll need to update the `gsub` command to properly extract what you need. The problem with `merge` may be related to this and/or not properly updating `allminutes`.

Comment: Yes, due to company policy i was actually not allowed to share the dataset. But I've uploaded three files (3 our of 1900 files, should be ok i guess?) on google drive and see if anyone wanna give it a try: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17Rq1Vx21VqZhwYKWl9HLWZzxoZh2mxIh?usp=sharing

Comment: Did it occur to you that your question showed sample data filenames as `20120204.dat` but your actual files are `FoodConsumption-20120206.csv` (CSV)? Did you change the `gsub` to account for that? Perhaps `gsub(".*(20[0-9]{6}).(dat|csv)$", "\\1", fn)` would work for you.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, yes I've done the necessary change (dat to csv) so that's not the problem. The problem remains at the dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M") line, at the paste function. In your example, the two dataframe x1 and x2 contains a time variable at X2. In my dataset, there is only data without the time variable. So dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M"), it couldn't find the %H:%M and hence not functioning properly. Now that I have found the issue, I will proceed to add time 00:00 - 23:59 into all my csv files first.

Comment: It would have helped to see a sample of the data to know that the 1-minute data did not have times (and a link to a google drive is not enough, I typically do not look at them). I have no idea how you think you can "fill out" a 1-minute data file to a full day without knowing when they occur, unless all you want to do is add a lot of `NA` to the end, in which case this answer is overkill. I suggest you do not *"add time into all csv files"*, since that seems an onerous task, but over to you.

Comment: Hi, nope i's rather easy. Just change this line dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")  to  dat$X2 <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")[1:nrow(dat)]