# When I use as.POSIXct command, the column becomes empty

Tags: r

This is just one part of a much larger problem.

I have a list of files called ABC_20120204.csv, ABC_20120205.csv and ABC_20120206.csv. Here's a snapshot of ABC_20120204.csv:

update: the files can be downloaded via google drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17Rq1Vx21VqZhwYKWl9HLWZzxoZh2mxIh?usp=sharing

or dropbox here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q6c9w8kryn2by5z/AAD3rPnBgP5CyRy7E5eautJGa?dl=0

```
   X.1    X      x      X2
1   1     1   0.0137    2
2   2     2   0.0059    3
3   3     3   0.0174    4
4   4     4   0.0073    5
5   5     5   0.0144    6
6   6     6   0.0103    7
7   7     7   0.0070    8
8   8     8   0.0017    9
9   9     9   0.0010   10
```

Each files have 3 columns, but each has different number of rows: 1st one has 864 rows, 2nd one has 1081 rows, and the third has 1439rows.

I am trying to apply a time stamp in each of the files by minute, so in the end every file will each have 1440 rows.

So far, from the discussion I've had with another forum member, I've tried this using made-up data:

```
fnames<-list.files(pattern="ABC")

first <- TRUE
times <- c("00:00", "23:59")

for (fn in fnames) {
thisdate <- gsub(".*(20[0-9]{6}).csv", "\\1", fn)
twotimes <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, c("00:00", "23:59")), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")

allminutes <- data.frame(X2 = seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min"))
dat <- read.csv(fn, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M") 

dat <- merge(dat, allminutes, by="X2", all=TRUE)

write.table(dat, "alldata.csv", append=!first, 
col.names=first, row.names=FALSE, sep=",", na="")
first <- FALSE
```

the code works wonderfully with dummy data ([How to automate data importing, add time stamp, and standardize the number of rows in data files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509864/how-to-automate-data-importing-add-time-stamp-and-standardize-the-number-of-ro/50518084?noredirect=1#comment88156825_50518084)). 
However, when i apply my real dataset, this line stopped working

```
dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

instead of appearing as date and time, the column X2 only has NAs in it.

```
   X.1    X      x      X2
1   1     1   0.0137    NA
2   2     2   0.0059    NA
3   3     3   0.0174    NA
4   4     4   0.0073    NA
5   5     5   0.0144    NA
6   6     6   0.0103    NA
7   7     7   0.0070    NA
8   8     8   0.0017    NA
9   9     9   0.0010    NA
```

I've tried another method, by using the following line instead:

```
dat$X2 <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")
```

but it says the number of rows are not the same. I have also tried merge, cbind, made a new data.frame, but it all boils down to one error: different number of rows.

I also tried

```
time <- seq(twotimes[1], twotimes[2], by="min")
M<-merge(dat, time)
```

and this time the dat and time merged, but the rows is the accumulation of timestamp from file A, B and C (about 2 million rows, for reasons unknown).

Anyone can give some tips on that line there:

```
dat$X2 <- as.POSIXct(paste(thisdate, dat$X2), format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement here.  If the `as.POSIXct` call is failing, then you should show us the exact data which was used when it failed.  Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: dear @TimBiegeleisen, I have updated the question with the sample data attached.

Comment: Please include the data directly in your question, _not_ as Google Drive links, which may break at some point.

Comment: I've uploaded it to dropbox as original csv file. I cant just copy it directly in question, because I guess there must be something with the csv that prevent the code from working, so I want to send it as it is to find out what have i done wrong initially.

Comment: I think few people will download your data and setup a full script.  What you may do is this: See if it runs with just one line of data.  If not, then you know the first (and probably all over) line has bad data.  If the first line _does_ work, then keep adding lines until it breaks, using bisection.  Maybe one (or more) lines has bad data.